# Why does this Linq method throw a Null Reference Exception

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq, nullreferenceexception

I have a `BaseApiController` which my controller inherits from. It overrides the `Initialize` method. The method will retrieve a JWT token from the `HttpControllerContext` and use it to retrieve the user making the request.

```
    public class BaseApiController : ApiController
    {
        public static tUser CurrentUser;
        public BaseApiController()
        {

        }

        protected override void Initialize(HttpControllerContext controllerContext)
        {
            base.Initialize(controllerContext);

            var request = controllerContext.Request;
            if (request.Headers.Authorization != null && request.Headers.Authorization.Scheme.Equals("bearer", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                CurrentUser = Helpers.JwtAuthentication.UserToken(request.Headers.Authorization.Parameter);
            }
        }
    }
```

The error happens, intermittently, when calling the `UserToken` method. Here is the method.

```
    public static tUser UserToken(string token)
    {
        string username = ExtractUserName(token);

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(username))
            return null;

        try
        {
            tUser user = Repository.DB.tUsers.Where(u => u.UserName == username && u.IsDeleted == false).FirstOrDefault();
            return user;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

The exception is thrown on the line `tUser user = Repository.DB.tUsers.Where(u => u.UserName == username && u.IsDeleted == false).FirstOrDefault();` and I can't tell why. If I examine the various objects in the line of code they aren't null. If I execute the debugger over the line of code again it runs with no problems.

Why does this line of code intermittently throw error 'Object reference is not sent to an instance of an object'?

```
    public class Repository
    {
        public static Entities DB = new Entities(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConnectionString"].ToString());
    }

    public partial class Entities : DbContext
    {
        public Entities(string secret) : base(Helpers.KeyVault.GetSecret(secret))
        {
            this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: `DB` is `lazy` and/or un-awaited async `dbContext`?

Comment: I've set `Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false` but the error still throws. It doesn't look like the DB context is being used async. I've added the code above

Comment: What is the lifetime of the `DbContext` you query through?

Comment: Try to directly new-up dbContext in UserTokens - also try it in `using` block.

Comment: I've put the query on tUser in a using statement and it looks like the error is not returning for now. I will work with it today and confirm that this is the resolution after more testing.

Comment: If this is the case, I would try to change the static `DB` in `Repository` to property like this: `public static Entities DB => new Entities(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConnectionString"].ToString());` This should guarantee new instance of `Entities` to be received each time you call for it. Now you only generate the context once, which is not great - creates problems with scopes. If This will fail, then problem lays in repository or Entities - something wrong with creation of it. If this will solve your problem, I'll convert comment to answer so it will be easier to be found for others.

Comment: Possible error even with retrieving connection string if somewhere in the repository / Entities there is a catch block that wont let connection error bubble up

Comment: Putting the code in a using statement seems to have been enough. The error did not return today. If you want to answer the question I shall accept it. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in comments, to ease search for others with similar issues:
"New up" `dbContext` directly in BaseApiController in `using` clock or with `using` statement (`using var ctx = new Entities(string secret)`) - this will do the trick.

Alternative would be to force `Repository` to always return new instance of `dbContext` by replaceing

```cs
public static Entities DB = new Entities(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConnectionString"].ToString());
```

with a property

```cs
public static Entities DB => new Entities(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConnectionString"].ToString());
```

It should resolve possible scope issue and do the trick if there is no problem with actually resolving custom `dbContext` class.